# PhotoViewer.dll for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, imagemagick

I know it comes with Windows 7, but is there an equivalent standalone module for XP's "Picture and Fax Viewer"?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What does PhotoViewer.dll have to do with ImageMagick?

Comment: ImageMagick's `win:` (and `show:`) output formats are hard-coded to look for it.